# suppress certain exceptions in overloaded Java constructors

Tags: java, exception, constructor-overloading

I have a class with a number of overloaded constructors. Depending on the constructor, an exception may occur (when either `startSize` or `growFactor` is too small). In other constructors, default values are used and these exceptions will not occur.

Is it possible to somehow suppress the warnings on the simpler constructors, as displayed below? I can't enclose them in a try-catch block since overloaded constructor calls have to be the first call.

```
private static final int DEFAULT_STARTSIZE = 50;
private static final int DEFAULT_SCALEFACTOR = 2;

public LinkedArrayList()
{
    this(LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_STARTSIZE, LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_SCALEFACTOR);
}

public LinkedArrayList(T... startCollection)
{
    this(LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_STARTSIZE, LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_SCALEFACTOR, startCollection);
}

public LinkedArrayList(int startSize) throws InitialSizeTooSmallException
{
    this(startSize, LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_SCALEFACTOR);
}


public LinkedArrayList(int startSize, T... startCollection) throws InitialSizeTooSmallException
{
    this(startSize, LinkedArrayList.DEFAULT_SCALEFACTOR, startCollection);
}

public LinkedArrayList(int startSize, int growFactor) throws InitialSizeTooSmallException, InitialGrowFactorTooSmallException
{
    if (startSize < 1)
        throw new InitialSizeTooSmallException();

    if (growFactor < 1)
        throw new InitialGrowFactorTooSmallException();

    this.data = new DLNodeList<T>(startSize, growFactor);
}

public LinkedArrayList(int startSize, int growFactor, T... startCollection)  throws InitialSizeTooSmallException, InitialGrowFactorTooSmallException
{
    this(startSize, growFactor);

    for (T item : startCollection)
        this.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appears rather often. Instead of throwing specific exception with no message you should throw `IllegalArgumentException` with correct message like 
`"Initial size is too small :" + startSize`.

For the reference see `ArrayList` initialization:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```